# How to check access token only if resource is secured in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In my Spring boot project I have some endpoints that require authentication and others don't. I'm using `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` dependency. The problem is when I want to access a resource that don't require authentication with an invalid access_token I get an error `"error": "invalid_token"`.
How can I prevent checking access token when if my method is not secured?

ResourceServerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/graphql/**")
                .permitAll();
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to disable spring security chain for a particular resource you can add ignore web request for pattern like below in your WebSecurityConfiguration class

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception
{
    webSecurity
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resourcename**");
}
```